# Can we merge two xml files using stax

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, stax

I have a requirement of merging two xml files.I am trying  to investigate  using stax parser. I am just concerned with only few particular elements as remaining elements are same in both the xml files. 
    For example:
    A.xml

```
<report>
    <measurement event-id="2170014015"/>
    <measurement event-id="2170014021"/> 
</report>


B.xml

<report>
    <measurement event-id="2170014011"/>
    <measurement event-id="2170014013"/> 
  <measurement event-id="2170014015"/>
</report>

Output:
<report>
    <measurement event-id="2170014015">
    <measurement event-id="2170014021"> 
  <measurement event-id="2170014011">
    <measurement event-id="2170014013"> 
</report>


These are for understanding purpose(but xml files are pretty big). What is the opinion on using jaxb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these files are really big, then I wouldn't recommend JAXB. Unless you're going to throw a ton of RAM at it. StAX will be the preferable option. See this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipstx5/) on how to merge multiple documents usin StAX.

Comment: Thanks. Ya i used Stax Parser and its Helping!